# JOIN DATA - ROWS TO COLUMNS?

Tags: mysql, sql

im noob please help me.

table1

```
id, options1, options2, options3
-----------------------------------------
1, 'a', 'b', 'c'
2, 'x', 'b', 'c'
3, 'c', 'b', 'd'
4, 'z', 'b', 'c'
```

table2

```
id, productid, name
-------------------
1, 1, "Title"
2, 1, "Color"
3, 2, "Title"
4, 3, "Title"
5, 4, "Title"
6, 4, "Color"
7, 4, "Size"
```

// a different number of rows for product_id (min=0 and max=3)

How to get:
table3

```
productid, new_name
--------------------
1, "Title a; Color b; c"
2, "Title x; b; c"
3, "Title c; b, d"
4, "Title z; Color b; Size c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'd leave a comment but I don't have the reputation points and yet I want to help you out.

Your schema is a bit wrong. These tables should be joinable by either ID or productID. If you run the following queries you will notice that these are not producing the result you wish and there is no way to attach the option in table1 to the product in the table2:

```
select table2.productid, * from table1 
full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

or

```
select table2.productid, * from table1 
full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.productid
```

You can rectify table 2:

```
table2
productid
id
value1 as nullable
value2 as nullable
value3 as nullable
```

Since I don't have these table in my database I hacked this table on the fly:

```
select 1 as id , 1 as productid , 'Title' as value1,'Color' as value2, null as value3  union
select 2 as id , 2 as productid , 'Title' as value1, null , null  union
select 3 as id , 3 as productid , 'Title' as value1, null , null  union
select 4 as id , 4 as productid , 'Title' as value1, 'Color' as value2, 'Size' as value3
```

this way your options match their values:

```
select 
    value1, options1,
    value2, options2,
    value3, options3
  from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

and this can be further refined into

```
select 
    productid,
    coalesce(value1,'') +' '+ coalesce(options1,'') + '; ' +
    coalesce(value2,'')+' '+ coalesce(options2,'') +'; '+
    coalesce(value3,'')+' '+ coalesce(options3,'') as new_name
     from  #tb3 join #tb1 on #tb3.id=#tb1.id
```

which yields the result you need:

```
productid   new_name
----------- ------------------------
1           Title a; Color b;  c
2           Title x;  b;  c
3           Title c;  b;  d
4           Title z; Color b; Size c
```

However, a better approach would be to create another table with separate options and in that table you could have 1 or many options (more than 3)

Please mark the answer if this works out for you. Thanks

Comment: You should create a new table and use that instead of table2. Your table2 example here does not describe how each options should be used. Do you already have a table in production or you're doing this for the frist time? If you have a table then maybe the solution should be around that and modify table1 to only have one option for each id.